# I’m trying to identify from what game a cardboard token I saw is from

Tags: identify-this-game, identify-this-game-piece

[image]

I have no idea what game this might be from. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What country was this image/token found?  
What context was this token found?  (grandma's house, found in roomate's sock?)
Every clue helps!

Answer (score 2):

That appears to be the game Jekyll vs Hyde and you can find more information on it on boardgame geek.

https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/297129/jekyll-vs-hyde

Comment: Thank you for your assistance

Comment: There’s a photo of the game clearly showing this token here: https://boardgamegeek.com/image/6128635/jekyll-vs-hyde

Answer (score 0):

Google image search brought up this game in french.  As I don't read French not sure what else to tell you.

https://paradoxetemporel.fr/31487-test-de-jekyll-vs-hyde.html

That said, as Philip Kendall states, there is more info at Board Game Geek:
[Jekyll vs Hyde](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/297129/jekyll-vs-hyde)

Comment: More info (as always) at [BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/297129/jekyll-vs-hyde).

Comment: Doh, of course.  I rarely use that site, so I never think of it!